# logs in Javascript

Tags: javascript, logging

In a Jsp file, I want to print some variable values in system logs. My alerts are working and this also working: `<% System.out.println( " now" ); %>`

But,

```
 <% System.out.println(actionURL ); %>
```

is not giving any results .

Plz gv me some insights.
I have invested so much time already but no result

```
<script>            
    window.onload = function()
    {
        var actionURL;
        var theForm = document.forms['reportForm'];
    <%
    // Incase of BROS do not post baseURl as parameter it will be set in Servlet
    // Incase of Non-Bros the url of the browser is treated as baseURL.
    String redirUrl=(String)reportParams.get("redir");
    redirUrl=redirUrl.toUpperCase();
    if(redirUrl.startsWith("HTTP://") ||  redirUrl.startsWith("HTTPS://"))
    {
    %>
        actionURL="<%=reportParams.get("redir")%>";
    <%
    }
    else
    {
    %>
        var docURL = document.URL;
        var urlStartingFromContext="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/webclient/common/openreport.jsp";
        var n =docURL.indexOf(urlStartingFromContext);
        var baseUrl=docURL.substring(0,n);
        if(baseUrl)
        {
            var input = document.createElement('input');
            input.type = 'hidden';
            input.name = 'baseUrl';
            input.value = baseUrl;
            theForm.appendChild(input);
            actionURL=baseUrl+"<%=reportParams.get("redir")%>";
        }
        else
            actionURL="<%=reportParams.get("redir")%>";
    <%
    }
    %>
    theForm.action =actionURL;
    reportForm.submit();
    };
</script>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: use single quotes inside get

Comment: it may be null so try `<% System.out.println("value of action url" + actionURL ); %>`

Comment: @AZ_ i tried it action URL giving proper value in alert but here gives null value.it makes me nut

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript runs in browser, there are no variable values there for your JSP. JSP can only turn your Java variables to strings, but JavaScript is just plain text in there.

Comment: means there is no way i can print that value in my system log??

Comment: If you need to log a value that is generated by JavaScript you would have to send it to your backend.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have experience in JSP, but it looks like you're rendering a HTML/JS template and inserting values between the `<% %>` brackets. Meaning you can print values coming from your server, but not vice-versa. When you render the code and the values get substituted, the file is sent to the browser. Therefore you cannot read values defined in Javascript back to your server. It's not a bidirectional data flow.

You can print into the HTML and into JS, but not from JS to ASP or C# or what is that server-side language you are using.